# JSON POST request object showing unevaluated keys

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I am trying to send an AJAX post request to Django.  I have a valid JSON object, which i can print/view/stringify in browser, but when it arrives in Django, the keys are unevaluated (see Django view in 2nd code block).

JS:

```
/* prettify payload for back */
var makeUpdatePayload = function(fieldType, fieldArray) {
  var orderInfo =  fieldArray.map(function(field, idx) {
    var fieldInfo = field.split('-field-')
    return {
      'pk': fieldInfo[1],
      'order': idx
    }
  });      
  return {[fieldType]: orderInfo}
};

/* post payload */
var updateFieldOrder = function( payload ) {
  console.log('in ajax')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(payload)) // {"search":[{"pk":"9","order":0},{"pk":"7","order":1},{"pk":"6","order":2},{"pk":"8","order":3},{"pk":"5","order":4},{"pk":"4","order":5}]}
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update_field_order/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(payload)),
  });
};

var payload = makeUpdatePayload('search', ["search-field-9", "search-field-7", "search-field-6", "search-field-8", "search-field-5", "search-field-4"])
updateFieldOrder(payload);
```

in my django view:

```
def update_field_order(request, recipe_pk):
    print('post')
    print(request.POST) # <QueryDict: {'search[0][pk]': ['9'], 'search[0][order]': ['0'], 'search[1][pk]': ['7'], 'search[1][order]': ['1'], 'search[2][pk]': ['6'], 'search[2][order]': ['2'], 'search[3][pk]': ['8'], 'search[3][order]': ['3'], 'search[4][pk]': ['5'], 'search[4][order]': ['4'], 'search[5][pk]': ['4'], 'search[5][order]': ['5']}>
```

I've tried JSON.stringify then JSON.parse -ing the payload before sending, but this doesn't help, I still see the same formatting.  With `JSON.stringify(payload)`, I get the expected output:

```
`<QueryDict: {'{"search":[{"pk":"9","order":0},{"pk":"7","order":1},{"pk":"6","order":2},{"pk":"8","order":3},{"pk":"5","order":4},{"pk":"4","order":5}]}': ['']}>`
```

Why is this happening?

I can see that the data is not correctly evaluated on sending:

[image: Form Data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *the keys are unevaluated*, but to send the object in the POST request, you should stringify it in your ajax call:

```
data: JSON.stringify(payload),
```

and then in your view, retrieve the JSON from the `request.body` and load it using the `json` module:

```
import json

...

payload = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
```